# Use class level field or method variable?

Tags: java, oop, class-design

I have a object I initialize in a method like :

```
public void something()
{
    Dummy obj = Factory.getDummy();
    method2(obj);
}
```

now, this `Dummy` object is to be used by many methods

```
public void method2(Dummy obj)
{
    method2(obj);
    ....
}
```

Now, my doubt is how this scenario must be handled, the way I am doing it. Or, make `obj` in `something` a class level field and initialize in `something`.

like:

```
private Dummy obj;

public void something()
{
    obj = Factory.getDummy();
    method2(obj);
}
```

And use in subsequent methods. (Removing parameters from the methods).

So, what is the best way of handling this situation? and Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. If it's strongly associated with the class, make it static.
2. If it's strongly associated with an instance, make it a non--static member.
3. If it's strongly associated with a method invocation, or the current thread, or you can't decide about (1) or (2), make it method-local.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare `obj` as a `class-level` field and then instantiate it in the constructor.

But more points to clear:

- if `something()` and the methods like `method2()` that expect the `Dummy` object, are located inside the same class, then you even don't need to pass the object. In that case, the above statement is upheld
- if not located in the same class, then pass the object by invoking the methods through their instances or classes based on what type they're.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should **minimize** the scope of one variable. But, if the variable is very used within your `class`, you should declare it as *class-level*, as instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

If some `property` is associated to class, then that property should be static. That is, if some property is same among all the instances of classes, then that `property` should be the static in class.

If some `property` is differing for every instance of class, then that `property` should be member variable ( non-static variable ) of the class.

If some property needs on temporary basis for some operation then make that property as local variable of the operation ( `method` ).